# Ubuntu 20.04 'packages have unmet dependencies'

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I've looked around and can't find a solution which works, using the software updater trying to update Ubuntu, I get the following error:

```
If you are using third party repositories then disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Now run the following command in a terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libc6-dbg: Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is installed
libc6-dev: Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is installed
           Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is installed
```

I get this error whenever using `apt-install` as well, what do I do?

Comment: Hi and welcome, The answer is right there in the first line If you are using third party repositories then disable them. After that run the command as listed in the second line. Now run the following command in a terminal: apt-get install -f

Comment: Hi, I did and I got the error: Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: ok you need to edit your question and say that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the focal-updates in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and install the packages from there.

```
apt install -t focal-updates libc6 libc-dev-bin
```

As you can see looking at the packages for it that is where the packages for that version come from. If you do not have that line in the file then they will never be installed and you are missing out on the upgrades.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all